# Can someone provide syntax reference for these below?

Tags: syntax, lex

```
%x ST_IN_SCRIPTING
%x ST_DOUBLE_QUOTES
%x ST_BACKQUOTE
%x ST_HEREDOC
%x ST_START_HEREDOC
%x ST_END_HEREDOC
%x ST_LOOKING_FOR_PROPERTY
%x ST_LOOKING_FOR_VARNAME
%x ST_VAR_OFFSET
%x ST_COMMENT
%x ST_DOC_COMMENT
%x ST_ONE_LINE_COMMENT
%option stack

LNUM    [0-9]+
DNUM    ([0-9]*[\.][0-9]+)|([0-9]+[\.][0-9]*)
EXPONENT_DNUM   (({LNUM}|{DNUM})[eE][+-]?{LNUM})
HNUM    "0x"[0-9a-fA-F]+
LABEL   [a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*
WHITESPACE [ \n\r\t]+
TABS_AND_SPACES [ \t]*
TOKENS [;:,.\[\]()|^&+-/*=%!~$<>?@]
ANY_CHAR (.|[\n])
NEWLINE ("\r"|"\n"|"\r\n")

%option noyylineno
%option noyywrap
```

So far I'm familiar with these 3 sections in lex,`{%...%}` , `%%...%%` and the section after `%%`,but have never seen syntax for the above yet...

Answer (score 1):

The following statement define a start condition

```
%x ST_IN_SCRIPTING
```

In some rule action you'll find `BEGIN(ST_IN_SCRIPTING)` and some rule patterns are prefixed by
`<ST_IN_SCRIPTING>`.

You'll find more information in [the Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html)